# probability distribution of suits from deck of cards

Tags: probability

standard deck of cards

draw 9 cards without replacement

Probability of getting at least 2 suits with at least 3 of each suit?

I know there could be a distribution like 
3,3,3,0 (this would be 3 suits with at least 3)

4,3,1,1 (this would be 2 suits with at least 3)

5,2,1,1 (this would be 1 suit with at least 3)

I know the minimum number would be 1 and the maximum would be 3.

I have no clue on how to start this other than list all combinations.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    Total Cases & WaysTo Select & Total \\
   3|3|3|0  & 4 & 4*13c3*13c3*13c3 \\
   3|3|1|2  & 12 & 12*13c3*13c3*13c1*13c2 \\
4|3|1|1  & 12 & 12*13c4*13c3*13c1*13c1 \\
4|3|2|0  & 24 & 24*13c4*13c3*13c2 \\
4|4|1|0  & 12 & 12*13c4*13c4*13c1 \\
5|3|1|0  & 24 & 24*13c5*13c3*13c1 \\
5|4|0|0  & 12 & 12*13c5*13c4 \\
6|3|0|0  & 12 & 12*13c6*13c3 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

Comment: so, it looks like listing all combinations is the way to go.   9,0,0,0;
8,1,0,0;
7,2,0,0;
7,1,1,0;
6,3,0,0;
6,2,1,0;
6,1,1,1;
5,4,0,0;
5,3,1,0;
5,2,2,0;
5,2,1,1;
4,4,1,0;
4,3,2,0;
4,3,1,1;
4,2,2,1;
3,3,3,0;
3,3,2,1;
3,2,2,2;
are what I come up with because there are 13 cards for each suit

Answer (score 1):

Consider the complementary event: we draw nine cards, and exactly three suits contain two or fewer cards.

There are $\binom{52}{9}$ hands, all of which we assume are equally likely.  We want to count the number of hands in which exactly three suits contain two or fewer (i.e. zero, one or two) cards.

There are $\binom{4}{3}$ ways to pick the three suits.

Given the three suits, if they contain $i, j, k$ cards respectively, then the number of possible hands is $$\binom{13}{i} \binom{13}{j} \binom{13}{k} \binom{13}{9-i-j-k}$$

So the number of hands in which three suits contain fewer than three cards each is
$$N_3 = \binom{4}{3} \sum_{i=0}^2 \sum_{j=0}^2 \sum_{k=0}^2 \binom{13}{i} \binom{13}{j} \binom{13}{k} \binom{13}{9-i-j-k}$$
The probability that there are three suits which contain fewer than three cards each is 
$$p = \frac{N_3}{\binom{52}{9}}$$
and the probability that there are at least two suits with three or more cards is
$$\boxed{1-p = 0.570226}$$

Comment: thank you so much. 1 - [1581171592 / C(52,9)]. so easy once shown how.

Comment: @Sally If you find an answer has met your needs, you should consider accepting it (click on the check mark).  This aids people who do searches of old questions.